# Does Firefox 72.0.2 try to establish a connection to wss://kre.kayako.net ? How could I find out, where the connection try does stem from?

Tags: firefox, security, console

I cannot figure out, where the following failing connection try does stem from. Any idea? (Firefox 72.0.2)

I regularily get in the browser console of my firefox the warning: (fingerprint and build-nr x-ed out by me)

```
Firefox kann keine Verbindung zu dem Server unter
wss://kre.kayako.net/socket/websocket?instance=codesector.kayako.com&fingerprint_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&vsn=1.0.0
aufbauen.
build-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js:14:293285
```

Translated:

> "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server under ...."

The `build.xxx-Javascript` is shown under the address:

```
view-source:https://assets.kayako.com/messenger/build-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js
```

and contains two copyright notices:

```
\* The buffer module from node.js, for the browser.
\*
\* @author   Feross Aboukhadijeh <feross@feross.org <http://feross.org>
\* @license  MIT
```

and

```
\* @license MIT or GPL-2.0
\* @fileOverview Favico animations
\* @author Miroslav Magda, http://blog.ejci.net
\* @source: https://github.com/ejci/favico.js
\* @version 0.3.10
```

As I have an SSD, I just used the windows explorer to search for the term `kayako.net` on the whole drive C: ; I also searched through every .xpi extension file I could find using winrar. Both searches found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably found the answer:

In the many many tabs I had constantly open, there were like three websites of the codesector-company. I didn't remember that company at all; I surfed there some time ago to download teracopy, and kept those tabs open about other software by them.

**But** I always assumed websites in those tabs, that are not looked at for some time, don't get their javascript executed in current Firefox versions! That's why I didn't check those old tabs at all so far.

I have closed those website now, and if I don't see any instance of that warning anymore in the javascript console in the next three days, I will mark my answer as correct.

If it's the websites, I really wonder why they would use the wss:// protocoll. I have never encountered that anywhere else. (The three open tabs' look and functionality were seemingly nearly plain html with barely any interactive javascript ui event.)